# Slow thread creation on Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, c++11

I have upgraded a number crunching application to a multi-threaded program, using the C++11 facilities. It works well on Mac OS X but does not benefit from multithreading on Windows (Visual Studio 2013). Using the following toy program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void t1(int& k) {
    k += 1;
};

void t2(int& k) {
    k += 1;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int a{ 0 };
    int b{ 0 };

    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        std::thread thread1{ t1, std::ref(a) };
        std::thread thread2{ t2, std::ref(b) };
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    }
    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time_stack = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
        end_time - start_time).count();
    std::cout << "Time: " << time_stack / 10000.0 << " micro seconds" <<
        std::endl;

    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have discovered that it takes 34 microseconds to start a thread on Mac OS X and 340 microseconds to do the same on Windows. Am I doing something wrong on the Windows side ? Is it a compiler issue ?

Comment: I ran your example here, http://rextester.com/HMWGM22211 and on avg I get 400 microseconds. Do you get similar results ?

Comment: The algorithm is not embarrassingly parallel and I need to parallelize some code that takes about 500 microseconds on a single CPU. It takes 30 microseconds to start a thread on Mac OS X. Why should it takes 300 microseconds to do the same on Windows?

Comment: Jagannath: Thanks for the tip. Yes, i get about 400 microseconds on this website too. It is the same as what I get on Visual Studio 2013 on my machine. But it is 10 times faster on Mac OS X and Linux on the same hardware.

Comment: Try with boost::thread to see if boost's implementation is any faster.

Comment: BTW, running using clang ( not sure on which platform it's hosted on ) http://rextester.com/TRXP85153 is much faster.

Comment: Jagannath: Interesting. But as there is no way to know which platform it runs on, it is very difficult to find what's going on.

Comment: Jagannath: I have tried boost::thread. It is a bit better and needs 240 microseconds to start. It is still 8 times slower than unices.

Answer (score 9):

Not a compiler problem (nor an operating system problem, strictly speaking).

It is a well-known fact that creating threads is an expensive operation. This is *especially* true under Windows (used to be true under Linux prior to `clone` as well).
Also, creating *and joining* a thread is necessarily slow and does not tell a lot about *creating* a thread as such. Joining presumes that the thread has exited, which can only happen after it has been scheduled to run. Thus, your measurements include delays introduced by scheduling. Insofar, the times you measure are actually *pretty good* (they could easily be 20 times longer!).

However, it does not matter a lot whether spawning threads is slow anyway.

Creating 20,000 threads like in your benchmark in a *real* program is a serious error. While it is not strictly illegal or disallowed to create thousands (even millions) of threads, the "correct" way of using threads is to create no more threads than there are approximately CPU cores. One does not create very short-lived threads all the time either.
You *might* have a few short-lived ones, and you *might* create a few extra threads (which e.g. block on I/O), but you will not want to create hundreds or thousands of these. Every additional thread (beyond the number of CPU cores) means more context switches, more scheduler work, more cache pressure, and 1MB of address space and 64kB of physical memory gone per thread (due to stack reserve and commit granularity).

Now, assume you create for example 10 threads at program start, it does not matter at all whether this takes 3 milliseconds alltogether. It takes several hundred milliseconds (at least) for the program to start up anyway, nobody will notice a difference.

Comment: Damon: In my case, this is an operating system problem as there is a ration of 10 in performance in between Linux and Windows. Here and in my real program, I only create 2 threads at a time. In a nutshell, my program does the following : Given a_0, compute a_1 = f(a_0), then a_2 = f(a_1), ..., f(a_(n+1)) = f(a_n). The only thing you could parallelize is the computation of f(x) which I do. It takes roughly 500 nanoseconds to compute it with one thread, and the parallelisation in 2 tasks is obvious. My idea was to create 2 threads every time I need to compute f(x).

Comment: As I have an OpenMP background, I thought I had to shut them down once the computation of one f(x) is over. But I have been suggested that it is not the case and that I should use a pool of threads.

Comment: OpenMP should (hopefully!) already use a pool and instead of spawning a new ones, wake threads from the pool on a condvar or similar whenever you write something like `#pragma omp parallel`, and put them to sleep again afterwards. A sane implementation of `std::future` should work similarly, but you have no guarantee for that (and no way of knowing). Parallelizing a single task that takes **500ns** is hard (well, it's not, but making it run _faster_ than serial code is near impossible). A context switch and cache miss already anihilates all gains, as does any synchronization primitive.

Comment: A context switch from synchronizing with a `futex` (which is _much_ faster than spawning a thread!) costs around 3,000 ns already as measured by [this guy](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html). So, in order to be able to actually gain anything from parallelizing, your task must either be at least a dozen times more complex, or you must queue up at least a dozen tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Visual C++ uses Concurrency Runtime (MS specific) to implement `std.thread` features. When you directly call any Concurrency Runtime feature/function, it creates a default runtime object (not going into details). Or, when you call `std.thread` function, it does the same as of ConcRT function was invoked.

The creation of default runtime (or say, scheduler) takes sometime, and hence it appear to be taking sometime. Try creating a `std::thread` object, let it run; and then execute the benching marking code (whole of above code, for example).

**EDIT:**

- Skim over it - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80825/Concurrency-Runtime-in-Visual-C
- Do Step-Into debugging, to see when CR library is invoked, and what it is doing.

Comment: Ajay: I have created a third thread that I launch before the loop and that I join after the loop. But it does not change anything on the timings.

Comment: Try running Release build.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand what I have mentioned. Try using a `thread` object, let it run, and dispose, and then do performance measurement. Or, may be actually the implementation is different.

Comment: Ajay: I have tried to use a thread object first and dispose it before the loop also. But it does not change anything. I am in release mode.